# Open an exe window

Tags: java

I want to customize the browser by adding a new button in the main menu the requirement is when i click on the button it should open an exe its working good by opening it in a new window i want the window to be displayed in the browser itself. eg. in mozilla firefox i give a button to open openoffice.exe. Its opening as a new window and i am able to close the browser by keeping the exe file opened. I want to open the exe file of open office in the browser so that when i click the link in the window it opens the new open office writer in the browser itself. Any idea how can i implement that

Comment: how is that related to java ?

Answer (score 1):

An exe file (Executable) file is an independent file. It will always run in its own window no matter from where it is called. If you want to open a document in your browser window, simple link the file created in that exe file. For example if you want to show a MS-Word document in the web browser, then instead of providing the link to MS-Word, provide a link to the Word documument (.doc or docx). Remember this behaviour requires that the linked files must have a registered application installed on the computer.